# “Not to speak to.”

Tags: grammar

> Say this dialog, “Do you know him?” “Not to speak to.” [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/speak_1)

I know what it means, but I am not sure what the complete version of “Not to speak to.” is.

And any rules to condense sentences like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's something like this:

> Alice: How well do you know him?
>   Bob: Not [well enough] to speak to [him].  *(= "[I do] not [know him well enough] to speak to [him].")*

Bob doesn't know him very well.  He probably doesn't have conversations with him very often, if ever.

> Alice: Do you know him?
>   Bob: Not [well enough] to speak to [him].

Alice's question here doesn't ask "how well" explicitly, but Bob doesn't have to give a yes-or-no answer.  It's perfectly appropriate for Bob to respond with "how well" he knows them.

(It might not be ellipsis, strictly speaking, but I think considering it ellipsis can help you understand what's being said here.)

Comment: +1 It might also be approached as an infinitive of purpose: "[I know him by sight, but ] not for the purpose of conversation"

Answer (score -2):

Something has to be missing there.  That exchange is almost nonsensical.

Could it be:

> Do you know him?
>
> [I know] not to speak to [him]. -implies there are adverse consequences to speaking to him
>
> Not [well enough] to speak to [him].  -implies you know of him, but not enough to carry a conversation -or- he is of some higher position and you're not comfortable doing so

There is also a third option (which I think now is what that example is trying to express).

> Not to speak to [his character]. -implies you knon him, but not well enough to offer a solid opinioin.

In other words:

> I can't speak to his character, but he seem like a nice guy.

Comment: Plz see the link in my question.

Comment: Well, it's the same as the quote above.  To a native speaker, that exchange as written doesn't make any sense.  "I know not to speak to him" or "Not well enough to speak to him" work.

Comment: I'm a native speaker and I'm familiar with the phrase, employed as snailplane describes.

Comment: Then there must be a local aspect to this.  From here, SEUS, that phrase "Not to speak to." doesn't make sense on it's own.  Even in the quoted context, it's ambiguous at best.